# How do I get a Wii Remote to communicate with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, three.js

If I connect my Wii Remote via bluetooth to my Ubuntu laptop with Wiican and like Wmgui, what'd be a basic program to show Wii Remote to browser interaction?

I've been able to get a Xbox Gamepad to work with chrome, that's not hard. But is this possible with the Wii?  First to get up, down, left, right to work and buttons, then possibly accelerometer input!

I guess I'd want a combination of this to start: 
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mesh-Movement.html -movement
and
https://github.com/s-haha-n/GameTPS/blob/master/sample.html -my sample Xbox gamepad output page.

Where should I start for something like this? Would the Gamepad.js just work off the bat with the Wii Remote?

Comment: Wiimote + Three.js? (ง ͠° ͟ل͜ ͡°)ง

Comment: I don't follow... Do you like this? Or not? Lol

Comment: I mean this is a very cool idea, but I can't really tell if it's possible in JavaScript. The native [Gamepad API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/gamepad/raw-file/default/gamepad.html) can handle gamepads that are supported by the client system, but if the system does not support it you can't really do anything about it. After all, JavaScript is designed to run in a sandbox, not interacting with hardwares.

Comment: Wiimote requires bluetooth. Why shouldn't we go with cellphones? Same (and much more) functionality and accessible everywhere. Maybe something like *cellphone app<-->WiFi<-->Computer<-->Browser*? Would an `adhoc` connection work?

Comment: Now I'm dreaming of a racing game done in browser and the user plays it with the cellphone like a gamepad ...

Answer (score 3):

If you can use a local server, you can

- catch events from a nodejs module such as https://github.com/bramp/nodewii
- forward these events to the browser over socket.io (nodewii [seems to do that](https://github.com/bramp/nodewii/blob/master/example/simple/client.html) also)
- use these events on client side to animate your three.js scene. Something like

```
socket.on( 'button', function( data ) {
  mesh.material.opacity = 1 - mesh.material.opacity;
})
```

Not sure about the events smoothness however, but it must be quite fun to try.

Comment: Thanks ! But I have seen that nodewii is compatible only with linux...How can we do if we are on Windows for example...

Comment: nodewii and other libcwiid-based libs seems a no-go on windows.
I would try to use another lib to produce events over websockets.
Maybe something liked here https://touchmote.codeplex.com ?